# Why I am getting bad results in 10-folds cross validation in Classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification, naivebayes

I am a new python programmer, and in classification as well. this is the first try for me playing with the pre-processing, and classification task using supervised data. data were collected by me using tweepy.

I am doing multi-class classification. I tried to clean up the data before train my classifiers, here is the scrpit I've used:

```
from flask import Flask, request 
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn 
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 
from string import punctuation 
import nltk 
import re 

data = []  # the tweet array 
target = []  # the category array 

file = open("readin file.txt", "r") 
count = 0 
for line in file:  # Declare 'line' variable and store the file into it
line_array = line.split(",,,") 
try: 
    data.append(line_array[4])  # appending tweet line into data array 
    target.append(line_array[0])  # appending categories into target array 
except:  
    pass  

stopWords = stopwords.words('english') 

stemmer = PorterStemmer() 

def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer): 
    stemmed = [] 
    for item in tokens: 
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item)) 
    return stemmed 


def tokenize(text): 
    text = text.lower() 
    text = text.lower() 
    text = text.replace("#","") 
    text = re.sub(r'((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))|(http?://[^\s]+)', '', text) 
    text = re.sub('&[^\s]+', r'', text) 
    text = re.sub('@[^\s]+', r'', text) 
    text = re.sub('#([^\s]+)', r'', text) 
    text = text.strip(r'\'"') 
    text = re.sub(r'[\s]+', ' ', text) 

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text) 
tokens_new = [] 

for item in tokens: 
    if "www." in item or "http" in item: 
        item = "URL" 
    if "@" in item: 
        item = "AT_USER" 
    if re.match("[a-zA-Z]",item) and len(item)>2\ 
        and "#illegalimmigration" not in item\ 
        and "#illegalimmigrants" not in item\ 
        and "#GOPDepate" not in item\ 
        and "#WakeUpAmerica" not in item\ 
        and "#election2016" not in item\ 
        and "#trump" not in item\ 
        and "#SanctuaryCities" not in item\ 
        and "#Hillary2016" not in item\ 
        and "#PopeVisitsUS" not in item\ 
        and "#tcot" not in item\ 
        and "#DonaldTrump" not in item\ 
        and "#PopeFrancis" not in item\ 
        and "#ACA" not in item\ 
        and "#NoAmnesty" not in item\ 
        and "#blm" not in item: 
        all = [] 
        for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets(item)): 
            all.extend(j.lemma_names()) 
            tokens_new.extend(list(set(all))) 

# print "Text " 
# print text 
# print "Tokens " 
# print tokens 
# print tokens_new 
stems = stem_tokens(tokens_new, stemmer) 
# print "Stems " 
# print stems 
return stems 

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 
count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopWords,tokenizer=tokenize) 
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(data) 

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer 
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts) 
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts) 

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer() 
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts) 


clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, target) 
scores = cross_val_score(clf,X_train_tfidf,target,cv=10,scoring='accuracy') 
print 'Naive Bayes Classifier' 
print scores 
print scores.mean() 
print
```

Data look like as an sample: 
category,,,countTweet,,,profileName,,,userName,,,tweet

```
1,,, 4,,,cjlamb,,,16campaignbites,,,@thinkprogress Let's give GOPers citizenship test. If they fail, they leave the country and immigrants stay 

2,,, 191,,,Acadi Anna,,,Acadianna32,,,#Deport the millions of #IllegalImmigrants in the United States illegally and build a wall between the U.S. &amp; Mexicohttp://t.co/AWJZBuZcJb 

3,,, 460,,,The Angry Vet,,,DemonTwoSix,,,RT @sweety125: @hempforfood @RickCanton But an illegal alien can be deported 5 times &amp; come back &amp; get #SanctuaryCities then kills a young
```

1,,, support opinion number 1 which is keep illegal illegals in the US. 2,,, support opinion number 2 which is deport all illegal immigrants. and 3,,, support opinion number 3 which is deport only criminal illegal immigrants
I am getting this output which is bad result for classification:

```
Naive Bayes Classifier 
[ 0.51612903  0.51612903  0.5         0.58333333  0.74576271  0.62068966 
  0.53448276  0.60344828  0.5         0.5862069 ] 
0.570618169592
```

Here is one example of the stems, text, new tokens, and tokens when I print it:

```
Text 
let's give gopers citizenship test. if they fail, they leave the country and immigrants stay 
Tokens 
[u'let', u"'s", u'give', u'gopers', u'citizenship', u'test', u'.', u'if',     u'they', u'fail', u',', u'they', u'leave', u'the', u'country', u'and', u'immigrants', u'stay'] 
New Tokens 
[u'Army_of_the_Pure', u'Army_of_the_Righteous', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'Army_of_the_Pure', u'Army_of_the_Righteous', u'net_ball', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'let', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'Army_of_the_Pure', u'Army_of_the_Righteous', u'net_ball', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'allow', u'permit', u'let', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'Army_of_the_Pure', u'Army_of_the_Righteous', u'net_ball', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'allow', u'permit', u'let', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'Army_of_the_Pure', u'Army_of_the_Righteous', u'countenance', u'net_ball', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'allow', u'permit', u'let', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Army_of_the_Righteous', u'countenance', u'net_ball', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'allow', u'permit', u'let', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'have', u'get', u'Army_of_the_Pure', u'Army_of_the_Righteous', u'countenance', u'net_ball', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'allow', u'permit', u'rent', u'let', u'lease', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'spring', u'springiness', u'give', u'spring', u'springiness', u'give', u'afford', u'spring', u'yield', u'springiness', u'yield', u'springiness', u'pay', u'hold', u'throw', u'present', u'have', u'gift', u'give', u'afford', u'spring', u'make', u'devote', u'yield', u'springiness', u'pay', u'hold', u'throw', u'present', u'return', u'have', u'gift', u'give', u'afford', u'spring', u'make', u'devote', u'yield',  u'apply', u'establish', u'founder', u'open', u'grant', u'pay', u'make', u'devote', u'throw', u'cave_in', u'impart', u'fall_in', u'chip_in', u'return', u'collapse', u'turn_over', u'afford', u'sacrifice', u'give_way', u'reach', u'hand', u'break', u'hold', u'generate', u'present', u'gift', u'dedicate', u'yield', u'leave', u'ease_up', u'commit', u'pass_on', u'citizenship', u'citizenship', u'test', u'trial', u'trial_run', u'tryout', u'trial_run', u'mental_test'] 
Stems 
[u'Army_of_the_Pur', u'Army_of_the_Right', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'Army_of_the_Pur', u'Army_of_the_Right', u'net_bal', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'let', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'Army_of_the_Pur', u'Army_of_the_Right', u'net_bal', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'allow', u'permit', u'let', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'Army_of_the_Pur', u'Army_of_the_Right', u'net_bal', u'LET', u'Lashkar-e-Taiba', u'allow', u'permit', u'let', u'Lashkar-e-Tayyiba', u'Lashkar-e-Toiba', u'Army_of_the_Pur', u'Army_of_the_Right', u'counten', u'net_bal', u'LET', u'pass', u'appli', u'establish', u'founder', u'open', u'grant', u'pay', u'make', u'devot', u'throw', u'cave_in', u'tryout', u'test', u'exam', u'trial_run', u'mental_test', u'psychometric_test', u'trial', u'mental_test', u'tryout', u'test', u'examin', u'exam', u'trial_run', u'mental_test', u'psychometric_test', u'trial', u'mental_test', u'tryout', u'test', u'examin', u'run', u'exam', u'trial_run', u'mental_test', u'psychometric_test', u'trial', u'mental_test', u'tryout', u'test', u'examin', u'run', u'exam', u'trial_run', u'mental_test', u'psychometric_test', u'trial', u'mental_test', u'tryout', u'test', u'examin', u'essay', u'run', u'exam', u'prove', u'trial_run', u'mental_test', u'psychometric_test', u'tri', u'trial', u'examin', u'mental_test', u'try_out', u'tryout', u'test', u'examin', u'essay', u'run', u'exam', u'prove', u'screen', u'trial_run', u'mental_test', u'examin', u'mental_test', u'try_out', u'tryout', u'test', u'examin', u'essay', u'run', u'exam', u'prove', u'screen', u'trial_run', u'mental_test', u'psychometric_test', u'quiz', u'tri', u'trial', u'examin', u'mental_test', u'try_out']
```

I would really appreciate your suggestions on how to make sure my data is cleaned and pure before classify and test.

Comment: What is your `target`? How much data do you train on? Make sure to remove duplicates.

Comment: target = the category label. 1,2, or 3 which is related to the three opinions I want to classify, I did that manually. Data is limited around 668 observations, 300 for class2, 150 for class1, and 15 for class3. I did remove the duplicates and removed the hashtags and links as descibed in the code above.

Comment: That may simply be too little training data.

Comment: I did added the segmentation hashtag too now, same results not improved. What could be best way to enhance it tho. Thanks for your replay.

Comment: You need many many many more Tweets to train a classifier. The reason is that Tweets are short (just a few words) and have very different words. If you remove all words you have only once in your training data, nothing remains. **You need plenty of words you have seen 10+ times (in different Tweets)**, and that are not generic terms like "monday".

Comment: So, you are saying the only solution is to increase observations in data. Well, I hope if there are some classifiers dedicated for limited data. Thank you @Anony-Mousse